# Ensure database has been updated before returning with Entity Framework and C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, race-condition

I have a situation where I am caching the contents of a table in the database.  I am using Entity Framework 6 against an SQL Azure back-end. When the data in the table is updated.The process looks a little like this:

- Receive data from UI
- Insert/Update according to current state of store
- Trigger Cache rebuild ( on separate service )

Then on the cache service

- Clear cache
- Load all entities from the table
- Add the collection to the cache

The code on the data service works along these lines- this is obviously a highly abstracted version, but it shows the steps we go through:

```
public void UpdateProperty( int newVal ) 
{
    SetNewPropertyVal(newVal);
    TriggerUpdateEvent( newVal );
}

private void SetNewPropertyVal(int newVal) 
{

     using (var context = new MyContext()) 
     {
         using ( var mySet = context.Set<MyEntityType>();
         {
              var record = mySet.FindRecordToUpdate();
              record.UpdateableFieldValue = newVal;
              context.SaveChanges();
         }   
     }
}
```

The problem is that although `context.SaveChanges()` has been called before the `TriggerUpdateEvent` is raised, when cache rebuild ( running in a separate, fully independent, thread against a separate instance of the `DbContext` ) retrieves the collection of entities, it contains the old value for the updated property. This looks like a race condition- if I put a simple `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the cache refresh it works consistently, but I can't believe that is a good solution to this problem.

How do I avoid triggering a cache rebuild until the Entity Framework has actually updated the data store? I thought a transaction might do the trick, but SQL Azure doesn't seem to offer them.

Comment: The store should have been updated after the `SaveChanges` (synchronous) call. Are you using `Async` calls in your real code? And when you say *Load all entities from the table*,  are your retrieving the entities through new `DbContext` instance?

Comment: These calls are all synchronous, but the entities are retrieved asynchronously in a different thread on a different service ( potentially on a different machine) with a new `DbContext` instance.

Comment: As far as it's not reproduced by putting `var data = new MyContext().Set<MyEntityType>().ToList();` between `SetNewPropertyVal` and `TriggerUpdateEvent`, I would concentrate on cache rebuild procedure - how it gets notified, what happens if it's still processing the previous update request etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In this case @ivan-stoev correctly explained that there is no reason for this code to fail synchronously. That lead me to explore the Cache rebuild process in more detail and there was a reliance on a second cache concealed away in an AutoMapper configuration that was causing the old value to show up in my searches.

So for anyone else who turns up with this problem, the bug isn't in this part of your code.